# Prevent other Admins from accessing my computer

Tags: windows-7, security, administration

**My Scenario**
I'm a developer, working with other developers in an enterprise environment. We all have administrative powers on all computers in the facility.

We pull little pranks on each other some times when someone leaves a computer unlocked. For example, flipping the screen upside down, or installing ridiculous chrome extensions like NCage. Our only unwritten rules are: nothing malicious, and no hacking. If you leave your computer unlocked, this is your punishment, but we don't use our admin powers to pull pranks. There's no justification.

One of our staff has started using admin powers to log on to other machines and alter settings, including registry settings. This is not going over well with our team

**My Question**
Is there a way to prevent specific users from accessing a computer, even when they have admin accounts? We are all using Windows 7 AD accounts.

Comment: If that 'One of our staff' is too stupid to listen to your "Don't do this" there's only one way: bring it to HR.  In other words: "If you don't know how to behave, you can go find another job". Don't try to solve this using tools, it's a waste of your time. It's the same as any colleague messing with my dev machine: he would get one warning only, then I would launch a formal complaint with management.

Comment: Disable remote access on your computer.  Of course that disables remote access to your computer even for you.  Sounds like this person shouldn't be an Administrator on the domain, you should adjust your work flow.

Comment: @JanDoggen I agree partially. We don't want to cause bad blood, so I'm just looking for a systematic approach first. I've read an article or two suggesting this request isn't possible, but they were old posts so I thought I'd ask just in case there are new options out there.

Comment: @Ramhound that's not a bad idea. But sometimes we work on-call and have to remote to our computers from home. So unfortunately it won't work.

Comment: @Frantumn - This means there is no way to prevent another user from logging into your computer.  If all users are Administrator on the Domain, they can change all settings unilaterally, what you are asking for is not possible without changing your workflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You (or your organisation) made someone admin in your computer. In other words you set 'I trust you completely. You can do whatever you want on this computer and I have no way to stop that.'

And you want to limit that power...

Those two do not combine well. Either you trust him/her to behave, or you do not make him/her an admin. Trying to partially counter the admin rights is a loosing battle and it is a battle fought with the wrong tools. The right answer is not the one which depends on something technical. Instead talk to him/her.

If that does not work then consider revoking all admin rights or talking to HR.

Comment: Fair enough. I just wish there was a way, not to reduce their overall permissions, but increase my securities locally to prevent that user from accessing it. So that they'd still be an admin on every other computer, but restricted on my machine. I get what you're saying though.

Comment: The last might be possible with group policies. But then the 'evil person' could just counter those. So yes, you can make it harder. But harder to do something is not the same as 'impossible to do something'

Comment: Thankfully, at our level, we can't (or maybe I should say, don't) change GPO's. So that might be a good solution. I'll talk to our system admins about that option. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You could try the group policy setting

```
Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment\Deny access to this computer from the network
```

even editing the value locally, without bothering/involving IT, but I agree that this is more of an HR issue than a technical one.

Comment: Would this prevent me from RDPing from home?

Comment: You would add the other person's account to that list, to block them specifically. The policy specifies a list of users or groups that should be denied access from the network.